# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I'm getting this particular error for a couple hours now and I still can't figure out for the life of me what's wrong with my select statement, I'm trying to connect 3 tables.

```
"SELECT POItem.PO AS 'Purchase_Order', POItem.Qty AS 'Quantity', 
POItem.BCurr as 'Currency', POItem.TotalCost, PO.Vendor, Master.Desc1 
FROM PO 
LEFT JOIN POItem ON PO.ID = POItem.PO AND 
INNER JOIN Master ON Master.IPN = POItem.IPN 
WHERE POItem.IPN = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' 
ORDER BY POItem.PO DESC"
```

Comment: there is no need of `AND` before an inner join.

Comment: If you are not familiar with MS Access SQL, it is best to use the query design window.

Comment: @akhilkumar Unfortunately there seems to be another error once i remove the AND. It says Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'PO.ID = POItem.PO INNER JOIN Master ON Master.IPN = POItem.IPN'.

Comment: @Fionnuala Will do! Will definitely try out the query design window!

Comment: @akhilkumar I've solved it now! Thanks for the effort! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `AND` keyword that is not necessary at this position (just in front of `INNER JOIN`). If you remove it and add brackets around the `LEFT JOIN`, your query should work:

```
"SELECT POItem.PO AS 'Purchase_Order', POItem.Qty AS 'Quantity', 
POItem.BCurr as 'Currency', POItem.TotalCost, PO.Vendor, Master.Desc1 
FROM (PO 
LEFT JOIN POItem ON PO.ID = POItem.PO) 
INNER JOIN Master ON Master.IPN = POItem.IPN 
WHERE POItem.IPN = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' 
ORDER BY POItem.PO DESC"
```

By the way, instead of including the value of `TextBox1.Text` in the string, rather use Parameters in order to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: MS Access is very fussy indeed about brackets on joins. This will not work.

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be another error once i remove the AND. It says Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'PO.ID = POItem.PO INNER JOIN Master ON Master.IPN = POItem.IPN'.

Comment: @Fionnuala is right, MS Access needs some more brackets. I update my post.

Comment: @Ange1 Left outer join is not used in MS Access.

Comment: @Markus It's working now with the brackets! I just had to change the INNER join to LEFT join and its working perfectly now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ange1 Thanks for the effort tho :) very much appreciated

Comment: Hi Melissa, StackOverflow allows you to accept answers that worked for you but it is not required. If you want to accept an answer, just click the little tick mark.